# Include parent node using XML::Parser

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I am trying to modify a Perl script that I found online that uses XML::Parser to identify the unique elements of an XML document and the number of times that each element occurs. The Perl script and its documentation can be found [here](http://johnbokma.com/perl/finding-unique-xml-elements.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Parser;
use File::Find;

@ARGV or die "usage: xmlelements DIR [DIR ...]\n";

my %element_count;

my $parser = XML::Parser->new(
    Handlers => {
        Start => \&start_element,
    },
);

find \&process_xml, @ARGV;
print "$_ ($element_count{ $_ })\n"
    for sort keys %element_count;
exit;


sub process_xml {
    $parser->parsefile( $_ )
        if substr( $_, -4 ) eq '.xml' and -f;
}

sub start_element {
    my ( $expat, $element, @attrval ) = @_;
    $element_count{ $element }++;
}
```

This generates an output such as this:

```
Account (15614)
Account_No (15504)
Active (15614)
Activity (6658)
Address (28098)
Address_1 (27548)
Address_2 (2033)
Address_3 (62)
Address_City (15)
```

My question is how can I also include the parent node in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent node name is given by `current_element` so do `$name= $expat->current_element . '/' . $element` and voilà! If you want to avoid the warnings for empty parent names, use `my $parent= $expat->current_element || ''; $name = "$parent/$element";`

So the handler becomes this:

```
sub start_element {
   my ( $expat, $element, @attrval ) = @_;
   my $parent= $expat->current_element || '';
   my $name= "$parent/$element";
   $element_count{$name}++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @mirod, that was exactly what I was looking for. I am very new to Perl, could you please tell me where in the script I should put that line of code? I keep getting an error regarding explicit package names.

Comment: you probably had a warning because you did not declare `$name` with `my $name;`. I have updated my answer to give you the complete code for the handler.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use current_element to get the full path? I'm now realizing that I need the grandparent node as well.

Comment: have a look at the docs for XML::Parser::Expat, either by doing `perldoc XML::Parser::Expat` or by using metacpan https://metacpan.org/module/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.41/Expat/Expat.pm You want the `context` method, which gives you the list of opened elements, from the root to, and excluding, the current one.